# Formula range has variable from another sheet

Tags: excel

I have a Sheet named *INDEX*, where cell A1 holds a formula which gives a string as a result. This result value is *BI13*. So, it makes A1 a variable of type string. A1 yields letters and numbers as value.

In another sheet Called *TEST*, I need to calculate the first minimum value of a range. This range is located in sheet *INDEX* and begins at cell AR13 and ends at a variable cell in line 13. This variable is defined by cell A1 and it can hold any string value as in:

[AR13 ... AS13 ... AT13 ... AU13 (...) BG13 ... BH13 ... BI13 ... BJ13] etc

**Content of cell B1 of Sheet TEST:**

`B1 = SMALL(INDEX!AR13:BI13;1)`  <--- This works fine if you manually insert BI13. But one just cannnot insert it like that, because BI13 is a variable value (value of type string), being the result of cell A1

This *BI13* is the string obtained as a value from cell A1,  which is located in sheet *INDEX*, as previously stated

**Content of cell A1 of Sheet INDEX:**

```
A1 = SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;AQ1;4);1;"")&13
```

AQ1 is a variable of type integer. This cell has an user imput value. In this example AQ1 = 61, which in turn corresponds to column 61 of the *TEST* worksheet. The number 13 corresponds to line 13 and is a constant.

A1 cell´s priority is to convert column number to column letter. In this case,  the above formula originates the string value BI13. To summarize, cell A1 is not equal to cell BI13. In fact, cell BI13 is another story, since it has an integer inside. Therefore, A1 value is not an integer, but a string.

**How can I accomplish that calculation in B1 ?**

Comment: It wouls be helpful to know **why** BI13.

Comment: BI13 is a name or the value of A1?

Comment: Maybe include your other formulas, show us what is going with your data , particularly this mysterious cell A1. And just out of habit I avoid naming sheets after functions - just a thought.

Comment: @Jeeped I improved clarifications. It seems a simple task, but I have been trying quite some time to make it work, to no avail.

Comment: @NiteshHalai BI13 is a value of A1.

Comment: @QHarr Complete formula was added.

Comment: so why didn't you just use `=ADDRESS(13; AQ1; 4)` in A1?

Comment: @Jeeped. I cannot do that. Your suggestion gives me: B1 = SMALL(INDEX!AR13:ADDRESS(13; INDEX!AQ1; 4);1). This yields an error #NAME as value. Note that I want the following: B1 = SMALL(INDEX!AR13:A1;1), where in place of A1 it should be written the variable value of type string "BI13"

Comment: Wny use cell A1 at all? Creating the cell address is unnecessary and problematic. Simply: =SMALL(INDEX!AR13:INDEX(INDEX!13:13;INDEX!AQ1);1)

Comment: @XORLX Your suggestion yields an error #NAME as value. Could you possibly validate it on your machine?

Comment: I take it you've translated INDEX and SMALL to the required language equivalents, if necessary?

Comment: @XORLX Sorry, but my Sheet name is "INDEX" and I misinterpreted it with the INDEX command. Hehehehe.I will do it later today and post the result. Thanks.

Comment: @XORLX Thank you for your effort, but it didn´t work either that way. Our friend Nitesh Halai came up with a working solution. Best regards and thank you again.

Comment: You should be more clear and explain WHY it didn't work. What result did it give? What result were you expecting? Nitesh Halai's solution is volatile, and can be avoided.

Comment: @XORLX Hello. it did not work because the result following your suggestion was: `#NAME?`; The expected result is: `BI13`

Comment: I suggest you research the reason a #NAME? error can occur. This can only be a mistake on your part, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the INDIRECT function to create a cell reference using a content of another cell:

```
=SMALL(INDIRECT("index!AR13:"&INDEX!A1),1)
```

Comment: Very well done. Tested and problem is solved, finally ! Helped me a lot dude. Have a nice week !